# Why doesn't this code work to set up basic Android OpenGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

Hey I am trying to just set up the basic structure for some basic graphics. However, when I run this code the app makes me force quit on the emulator. I am using Android 2.3.

I used this website to get this far http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es10.html

Please help. I am familiar with OpenGL just not for Android

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private GLSurfaceView mGLView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGLView = new GLSurfaceView(this);     
    setContentView(mGLView);
}

@Override protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mGLView.onPause();
}

@Override protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mGLView.onResume();

}

   }

class SampleSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView
{

public Sample2SurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    setRenderer(new SampleRenderer());
}

}

public class SampleRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer 
{
private FloatBuffer triangleVB;
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
{    
    gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
}       
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{        // Redraw background color    
      gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    }    
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
{   
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }
```

10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {android.SampleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.onResume(GLSurfaceView.java:512)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.TagToMobileAlbum.TagToMobileAlbumActivity.onResume(TagToMobileAlbumActivity.java:28)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
10-03 00:25:57.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     ... 12 more
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {android.TagToMobileAlbum/android.TagToMobileAlbum.TagToMobileAlbumActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.onResume(GLSurfaceView.java:512)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.SampleActivity.onResume(
SampleActivity.java:28)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
10-03 00:34:05.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     ... 12 more

Comment: Please post the stacktrace you receive in Logcat when the app force closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem and, from looking at other sample code, managed to solve it.  I'm not sure why it makes a difference but I moved the call to setRenderer into the Activity constructor and this seems to have solved the problem.  So your onCreate would be something like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGLView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    mGLView.setRenderer(new SampleRenderer())
    setContentView(mGLView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Your constructor for `SampleSurfaceView` does not match the name of the class.

2) You need to set the `SurfaceView`'s `Renderer` before you set the `ContentView`.

Among other things, you don't ever seem to be using `SampleSurfaceView`. If you want to extend `GLSurfaceView`, you need to use that extended class. Switch your private `GLSurfaceView` and all instances of it to `SampleSurfaceView`. Currently your `SampleSurfaceView` class is never used.